# Local Git repository url in Visual Studio error: Unsupported URL protocol

Tags: git, visual-studio, url, raspberry-pi, visual-studio-2015

I configured my own git server on my raspberry pi using this tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-up-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-git-server/

This worked fine and I continued by downloading git for windows: https://git-for-windows.github.io/

I connected to my local git repository with an url like this: git@192.168.xxx.xxx:/home/git/Hello-World.git

I was able to commit and push changes to my raspberry. Therefore I wanted to try that in my Visual Studio Community 2015. I added the folder where the git-for-windows GUI placed the cloned repository and was able to change files and commit them. But Visual Studio told me that I need to sync the changes to the remote repository. That seemed right to me. I clicked on Sync and then Publish (Push is disabled). That didn't work and an error told me that the URL protocol is unsupported.

"Error encountered while publishing branch to the remote repository: Unsupported URL protocol"

I don't know what is wrong with this URL because it is working in the git-gui.
Is there a quick fix for it? Did I miss something?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. To workaround, I used TortoiseGit to Sync to the remote.  VS 2015 noticed the sync indicating _There are no outgoing commits._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Team Explorer with repos managed via the SSH protocol are still not supported. See here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1290535/unsupported-url-protocol-in-git-provider

Comment: Thank you for that information. Is there a better workaround than using another software to push to the git server?

Comment: There's a few workarounds, just depends on your workflow restrictions or preferences.

You can:
1. Change the security protocols of the repo, your account, or both to use HTTPS instead of SSH.
2. Create another account that does not use 2FA and reconfigure the local to use that user and the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try them.

Comment: Isn't it a shame that in 2017 `vs` is not able to handle `ssh`?

Comment: It's not a shame, it's ridiculous!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem for bonobo git server. Problem is a wrong git configuration file created. Open the file .git\config, check the url and remove additional space.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio:
1. Go to Team Explorer->Home->Git settings->Global settings
2. Set ENABLED: [x] Enable download of author images from 3rd party source.
3. Restart VS

Comment: This is actually the top answer, though in VS2022 the checkbox is found in Tools->Options->Source Control->Git Global Settings

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio 2015. In the top menu click "Team" -> "Manage Connections...". In "Team Explorer", click "Manage Connections", "Connect to Team Project", Add Team Foundation Server

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you explain your solution? It's not clear how adding TFS would resolve the original poster's Git problem.

Comment: He's saying to use TFS and get rid of git.